# wxwidgets cannot find gtk

Tags: build, wxwidgets, gtk3, pkg-config

Building wxwidgets samples via https://github.com/wxWidgets/wxWidgets/blob/master/samples/widgets/makefile.unx

gave me this error:

```
$ make -f makefile.unx
`wx-config --cxx` -c -o widgets_native.o -I. `wx-config --cxxflags --unicode=yes --static=no --toolkit=gtk3 --version=3.2`   -MTwidgets_native.o -MF`echo widgets_native.o | sed -e 's,\.o$,.d,'` -MD -MP native.cpp
native.cpp:146:10: fatal error: gtk/gtk.h: No such file or directory
  146 | #include <gtk/gtk.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make: *** [makefile.unx:182: widgets_native.o] Error 1
```

But I have gtk3 installed of course:

```
$ pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-3.0
-pthread -I/usr/include/gtk-3.0 -I/usr/include/at-spi2-atk/2.0 -I/usr/include/at-spi-2.0 -I/usr/include/dbus-1.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dbus-1.0/include -I/usr/include/gtk-3.0 -I/usr/include/gio-unix-2.0 -I/usr/include/cairo -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/harfbuzz -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/fribidi -I/usr/include/harfbuzz -I/usr/include/atk-1.0 -I/usr/include/cairo -I/usr/include/pixman-1 -I/usr/include/uuid -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0 -I/usr/include/libpng16 -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu -I/usr/include/libmount -I/usr/include/blkid -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include -lgtk-3 -lgdk-3 -lpangocairo-1.0 -lpango-1.0 -lharfbuzz -latk-1.0 -lcairo-gobject -lcairo -lgdk_pixbuf-2.0 -lgio-2.0 -lgobject-2.0 -lglib-2.0
```

But `gtk-config` is not `wx-config`. So what should I do?

Comment: did you build wxWidgets itself successfully? How? What OS did you build it on?

Comment: also where are you running the command from? If you do it from the directory where the source code is - you are wrong!! And finally - it looks like you are trying to build it as `root`. If its the case - you are wrong!!!

Comment: Please show `wx-config --cxxflags` output, it must be wrong, but it's difficult to say how/why without knowing what it is. Also, what does `which wx-config` show?